# How to setup Silverlight xap caching to work the same in all browsers

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, caching, silverlight-4.0

**Basic Requirements**

I have a SL app that can be run in-browser or out-of-browser. I want the browser to:

- Cache the xap file
- Load the xap from the cache if it has not changed or re-download it if it has changed.

**More details**

Setting a future `expires` header obviously solves the caching problem but then I cannot force the user to download the latest version. Normally I would just add a querystring to the url (eg `url?v=1`) but I cannot do this as this breaks the out-of-browser functionality. eg the app thinks it is not installed when in fact it is.

**no cache**

If I set `Cache-Control` to `no-cache`, Chrome and Firefox correctly send a request to the server for the xap but use the cache if a 304 is returned. IE8 just downloads the file again as does Safari.

**must-revalidate**

Setting `Cache-Control` to `must-revalidate` again works correctly in Chrome and Firefox but Safari always downloads the xap again while IE8 always uses the cache.

How do I set this up to work as described at the start of this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that the Chrome/Firefox is strictly "correct", you have after all not told the browser that it should cache the content or even that the content is cacheable.

Instead of no-cache try "Cache-Control: max-age=15" instead.  See if that convinces IE that it ought cache the content despite its large size (which is why its not caching it originally).

For OOB install use the `Application` object's `CheckAndDownloadUpdateAsync` method.  Note you need to inform the user to restart the app once an update has been downloaded.

Comment: thanks, that's done the trick for IE. Safari always reloads it from the server, but I guess I can live with that. I don't have a problem with updating the oob, but rather installation status is incorrectly detected in the in-browser app if you change the url.(eg to show an install button etc)

Comment: actually caching in Safari on the Mac does work. Its just on Windows where it doesn't and we all know that no-one uses Safari on Windows :). So problem solved. Thanks again.